# HTML parsing to file from directory with java and Jsoup

Tags: java, list, arraylist, hashmap, jsoup

I am having trouble with parsing some html files from a directory into an output directory. I'm using Jsoup to remove HTML tags and writing to an output directory but some of the data is lost when I'm testing it. What I want to do in the end with the parsed files is to populate a hashmap so that I can sort the words by frequency and then in a separate directory sort them by alphabetical order. This compiles and runs, but I am getting stuck at the very end when it comes to write out. Code would be lovely and all, but I'm only interested in the steps to take in order to set this entire thing up. Thank you.

Update: Here is code.
Update: Also I feel like Jsoup is getting rid of data.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class Parser {

    public static File infolder = new File("input folder folder path goes here");
    static String temp = "";
    static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        String outfolder = "output folder path goes here";

        File theDir = new File(outfolder);
        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + outfolder);
            boolean result = theDir.mkdir();
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("DIR created");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Reading files under the folder " + infolder.getAbsolutePath());
        parseFiles(infolder);
        // System.out.println();
    }

    public static void parseFiles(final File folder) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isFile()) {
                temp = fileEntry.getName();
                if ((temp.substring(temp.lastIndexOf('.') + 1, temp.length()).toLowerCase()).equals("html")) {
                    System.out.println("File= " + folder.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileEntry.getName());
                    File file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + fileEntry.getName());
                    ArrayList<String> filetext = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);

                    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                        filetext.add(in.nextLine());
                    }

                    String filename = "tokenfile" + fileEntry.getName();

                    try {
                        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/Users/bounty213/Desktop/Output/" + filename + ".txt", true)));
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) {
                        //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
                    }

                    String parsed;
                    for (String word : filetext) {
                        parsed = Jsoup.parse(word).text();        
                        System.out.println(parsed);
                        out.println(parsed);
                    }
                    out.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you could give us the code you've been trying to run it would be helpful for us to understand better.

Comment: Parsing the HTML file line by line is weird. Why don't you want to use `parse(File in, String charsetName)` or `parse(InputStream in, String charsetName, String baseUri)`?